# Synchronize same table between two databases in mysql

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two databases with same table, this table stores products selling, i want to synchronize these two databases such us they must have same table products.

For example if i decrement or increment a stock in database A i want it to do the same think in database B, i use another table called stock in two databases wich stores mouvements of my stock so if i insert a mouvement in database A i want to have the same data in database B.

I'm using triggers for updating stock items.

I tried dynamic SQL in a procedure and call it from a trigger but MySQL by design does not allow me.

So my question is: Can i do replication between two databases but only specified tables?

Comment: If they are always the same why have two of them?  Use this syntax to reach into a different database:  `SELECT ... FROM db2.tbl ...`

Comment: What @RickJames said, or if application code can't be changed then make the table an updateable view in one of the databases: `CREATE VIEW db2.tab AS SELECT * FROM db1.tab`

Comment: @RickJames i need to update stock in table2 because i'm using trigger for that that why i want an insertion

Comment: I don't understand why all stock activity isn't in a single table in a single database.

Comment: By "database" are you referring to `CREATE DATABASE`?  Or a server with an instance of MySQL?